# Why some Java wrapper classes have different names than their primitive types?

Tags: java, wrapper, primitive

Is there a reason for some wrapper classes to have the same name as primitives with different case (i.e. boolean/Boolean), and some not (i.e. int/Integer)?

I don't want opinions, but knowing if the cause is based on a relevant design decision for what seems to be an inconsistency.

Comment: Uhm, "because yes"? I don't see that there are any particular reasons, except maybe to "attract" developers (or not rebuke them) from existing languages at the time (the C family in particular)

Comment: int from C and C++.  The person who wrote the wrapper thought spelling out Integer for the wrapper was more appropriate.

Comment: This was done in Java 1.0 - Sun, not Oracle.

Comment: The first letter of the class should be in Upper case as per naming convention

Answer (score 1):

It's likely because Java was created to attract C/C++ developers.

`int` was from C++, which took it from C.

`boolean` as opposed to pre-C99 typedef'd `bool` was first used in [ALGOL 60](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type). C++ has a separate data type called `bool`. I don't think ALGOL 60 actually had the name `boolean` however. It is named after George Boole, who first defined an algebraic system of logic in the mid 19th century.

As far as why the autoboxed Class name vs the primitive name, well the primitive name already existed like I described. Since you would likely have a confusing time telling the different between `int` and `Int` in code, it was made more explicit. In Java, by convention, class names are in `CamelCase`. Thus, Integer is spelled out and capitalized.

Comment: The question isn't why `int` is called `int`, nor why it isn't called `integer`, but why the associated wrapper class is inconsistent w.r.t. the primitive's name.